# How to delay button animation inside for loop?

Tags: java, android, animation

I am trying to animate list of buttons from for loop sequentially but they are animating at the same time.

```
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    for(int j=0;j<10;j++) {
        String finalId = Integer.toString(j);
        int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(finalId, "id", getPackageName());
        AppCompatButton btnNew = findViewById(resID);
        btnNew.setText(j);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

     btnNew.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this,R.anim.btnanim));
            }
        }, (j+1)*1000);
    }
```

How to make them animate one by one. Please Help.

Comment: are you talking about animation should work one after another or all animation at a time

Comment: @AndroWaqar. I want it to work one by one i.e button by button.

Comment: so you can use offset to do that kind of magic

Comment: for first button animation set duration accordingly for example for button1 animation will be myanimation1.setDuration(200); & for second button add myanimation2.setStartOffset(200); with myanimation1.setDuration(200);

Comment: it does not work

Answer (score 0):

You can set and use **Animation Listner** which will overrides your first animation after one animation to second another

```
myanimation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        //when on animation end
        bloby.startAnimation(myanimation1);

    }
});
```

or you can also set

```
myanimation.setStartOffset(200);
```

Comment: This code does not work. Button is inside the for loop.